# GeoServer WPS gs:Aggregate throws: Filter type not supported error

Tags: geoserver, xml, gml, wps, ogc

I'm using the WPS gs:Aggregate function with an OGC filter. When I use an OGC filter with PropertyIsEqualTo it works. But when I use a geometry filter it throws the error 'Filter type not supported'.

---

I tested this with gs:Bounds and there it works. Am I doing something wrong or isn't it possible to do a geometry filter with gs:Aggregate?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
    <ows:Identifier>gs:Aggregate</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:DataInputs>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                <wps:Body>
                    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" >
                        <wfs:Query typeName="art">
                            <ogc:Filter
                                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
                                xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                                <ogc:Within>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <gml:Polygon>
                                        <gml:exterior>
                                            <gml:LinearRing>
                                                <gml:posList>113973 477318 115635 477371 115512 475948 113974 476050 113973 477318</gml:posList>
                                            </gml:LinearRing>
                                        </gml:exterior>
                                    </gml:Polygon>
                                </ogc:Within>
                            </ogc:Filter>
                        </wfs:Query>
                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                </wps:Body>
            </wps:Reference>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>aggregationAttribute</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>material</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>function</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>Count</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
        <wps:Input>
            <ows:Identifier>groupByAttributes</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>material</wps:LiteralData>
            </wps:Data>
        </wps:Input>
    </wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:ResponseForm>
        <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
            <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
        </wps:RawDataOutput>
    </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:ExecuteResponse
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" service="WPS" serviceInstance="" version="1.0.0">
    <wps:Process wps:processVersion="1.0.0">
        <ows:Identifier>gs:Aggregate</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Aggregate</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>Computes one or more aggregation functions on a feature attribute. Functions include Count, Average, Max, Median, Min, StdDev, and Sum.</ows:Abstract>
    </wps:Process>
    <wps:Status creationTime="2022-08-08T13:10:07.980+02:00">
        <wps:ProcessFailed>
            <ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0">
                <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
                    <ows:ExceptionText>Process failed during execution java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQLException: Filter type not supported org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQLException: Filter type not supported Filter type not supported</ows:ExceptionText>
                </ows:Exception>
            </ows:ExceptionReport>
        </wps:ProcessFailed>
    </wps:Status>
</wps:ExecuteResponse>
```

I enabled logging developer mode and got this error. Do you know what throws the error?

```
2022-08-11 09:39:01,313 INFO [org.geoserver.wps] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2022-08-11 09:39:01,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd
2022-08-11 09:39:01,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0: http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd ==> jar:file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.62/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wps-26.4.jar!/org/geotools/wps/wpsAll.xsd
2022-08-11 09:39:01,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - No schemaLocation found, using 'http://www.opengis.net/wfs jar:file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.62/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-26.4.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
2022-08-11 09:39:01,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wfs: jar:file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.62/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-26.4.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd ==> jar:file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.62/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wfs-26.4.jar!/org/geotools/wfs/v1_1/wfs.xsd
2022-08-11 09:39:01,333 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,333 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,336 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field false in class class org.geotools.process.vector.AggregateProcess
2022-08-11 09:39:01,336 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field false in class class java.lang.Boolean
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd] - [ class java.lang.String ] is not of type interface org.opengis.filter.expression.PropertyName
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd] - Found multiple non-abstract bindings for AbstractGeometry: [Ljava.lang.Object;, [Ljava.lang.Object;, 
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd] - [ class org.locationtech.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequence ] is not of type class [Ljava.lang.Double;
2022-08-11 09:39:01,339 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,339 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2022-08-11 09:39:01,339 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd] - [ class org.locationtech.jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequence ] is not of type class [Ljava.lang.Double;
2022-08-11 09:39:01,339 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field false in class class org.geotools.process.vector.AggregateProcess
2022-08-11 09:39:01,339 DEBUG [org.geotools.process.factory] - Failed to locate the field false in class class java.lang.Boolean
2022-08-11 09:39:01,339 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2022-08-11 09:39:01,340 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2022-08-11 09:39:01,340 ERROR [org.geoserver.wps.executor] - Process execution failed
org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQLException: Filter type not supported
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:649)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:50)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:222)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:191)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQLException: Filter type not supported
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.filter(JDBCDataStore.java:3495)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.filter(JDBCDataStore.java:3471)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.doSelectAggregateSQL(JDBCDataStore.java:3975)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.selectAggregateSQLPS(JDBCDataStore.java:3875)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getAggregateValue(JDBCDataStore.java:1432)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.handleVisitor(JDBCFeatureSource.java:703)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.handleVisitor(JDBCFeatureStore.java:223)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.accepts(ContentFeatureSource.java:792)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.accepts(ContentFeatureCollection.java:126)
    at org.geoserver.security.decorators.SecuredSimpleFeatureCollection.accepts(SecuredSimpleFeatureCollection.java:83)
    at org.geotools.feature.collection.DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.accepts(DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.java:60)
    at org.geotools.process.vector.AggregateProcess.handleGroupByVisitor(AggregateProcess.java:267)
    at org.geotools.process.vector.AggregateProcess.execute(AggregateProcess.java:148)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor562.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:633)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQLException: Filter type not supported
    at org.geotools.geopkg.GeoPkgFilterToSQL.encode(GeoPkgFilterToSQL.java:112)
    at org.geotools.data.jdbc.FilterToSQL.encodeToString(FilterToSQL.java:309)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.filter(JDBCDataStore.java:3482)
    ... 23 more
2022-08-11 09:39:01,348 INFO [org.geoserver.wps] - 
Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://tutorials.kaartviewer.nl/geoserver/
    identifier:
        value = gs:Aggregate
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@25a57e7b (value: features, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@10d5db6b (body: net.opengis.wfs.impl.GetFeatureTypeImpl@681b8179 (handle: null, service: WFS, version: 1.0.0, baseUrl: null, providedVersion: null, extendedProperties: {}) (maxFeatures: null, outputFormat: GML2, resultType: <unset>, traverseXlinkDepth: null, traverseXlinkExpiry: null, formatOptions: null, metadata: null, startIndex: null, viewParams: null), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wfs, method: POST, mimeType: text/xml, schema: null)input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@5d26a2ab (value: aggregationAttribute, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@537e59d2input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@6dcede55 (value: function, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@596a9adcinput[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@313158a0 (value: groupByAttributes, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@1020279d
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@b877fba (value: result, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = application/json
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I think you'll need the `ogc` namespace for `query` and `Within`

Comment: I updated the request and I still got the same error. I also enabled logging en added the error. Did I made a mistake or is this not possible with WPS in GeoServer?

Comment: I would suggest that this might be related to https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7161 - which should have fixed this problem.  Though also `WIthin` should be supported by any of the JDBC stores. Can you add some more of the log below the ProcessException line

Comment: I added the full error log of the request.

Comment: I checked my GeoServer and I was running 2.20.4. I updated it to 2.20.5 and now it works! Thanks for your quick response! 

I'm looking forward to attend your presentation about 'How to get a good response on stackexchange' at Foss4G in Florance!

Comment: If I see you in a pub in Florence you will get a big glass of beer from me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that this might be related to http://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7161 - which should have fixed this problem. That fix will be in GeoServer 2.20.5 and 2.21.1 and later releases.